# Is there a way to pass custom test data into an XGBoost prediction model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I've fitted my training and testing data, and now I am trying to give my XGBoost model custom made data. This data is in the same format as my train and test, but it is a 1D array instead of 2D. I keep getting error `TypeError: can not initialize DMatrix from Series`

Here is my code:

```
#create test data series
newcol = ["away", "home"]
#enter names of teams to get
testrow = pd.Series(["Seoul Dynasty", "Dallas Fuel"], index=newcol)

#get all stats for each team
awayrow = get_team_stats(testrow[0])
homerow = get_team_stats(testrow[1])

#convert columns to proper team placement
awayrow = awayrow.rename(lambda x: "Away " + x)
homerow = homerow.rename(lambda x: "Home " + x)

#turn name into id
for name, team in ID_TO_NAME.items():
    if team == testrow[0]:
        testrow[0] = name
    if team == testrow[1]:
        testrow[1] = name
testrow = pd.concat([testrow, awayrow, homerow])
testrow = testrow[~testrow.index.str.contains("Rank")]

#predictions
rfcprediction = rfc.predict([testrow])
lrprediction = lr.predict([testrow])
knnprediction = knn.predict([testrow])
svprediction = sv.predict([testrow])

testrow = np.array([testrow]).reshap((1,-1))
xgprediction = xgboost.predict(testrow)

#turn id back into name
def convert_prediction(prediction):
    if prediction[0] == 1:
        #Home Won
        return ID_TO_NAME.get(testrow[1])
    if prediction[0] == 0:
        #Away Won
        return ID_TO_NAME.get(testrow[0])


print("Random Forest Prediction: ", convert_prediction(rfcprediction))
print(" ")
print("Logistic Regression Prediction: ", convert_prediction(lrprediction))
print(" ")
print("K Nearest Neighbors Prediction: ", convert_prediction(knnprediction))
print(" ")
print("SVC Prediction: ", convert_prediction(svprediction))
print(" ")
```

I was told to reshape the array (which is a series type), but that gave me a feature_names mismatch. How can I do an XGBoost prediction for a 1 row series?